# Как можно определить что строка UTF - 8 находится в верхнем регистре?

Tags: php

```
$word_1 = randomWord();
$word_2 = randomWord();
```

нужно сделать проверку на то, чтобы одно из слов было полностью в верхнем регистре, и вернуть true или false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения:

```
$bool = randomWord('Разные СЛОВА дЛя примера');
var_dump($bool);

function randomWord($words) {
    return (bool) preg_match('~\b[А-ЯЁA-Z]{2,}\b~u', $words);
}
```

Результат:

```
boolean true
```

Answer (score 2):

Заносишь в переменную $string слово введённое пользователем, затем переводишь его в верхний регистр

> string strtoupper ( string $string )

После этого сравниваешь то, что у тебя в $string и то, что по факту ввёл пользователь. Если они совпадают, соответственно слово в верхнем регистре